# bugs accuring during spring batch scheduling

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-scheduled

hey guys i am working on spring batch with scheduling (using cron trigger) it is working but with bugs which are the following:

- let's assumme that the cron value launches the batch each 10 seconds, when i launch the first and after, for example 3 seconds I launch another one, spring will not be aware of the gap of the 3 seconds and it will launch them both like i have triggered them in the same time

here is my code

> this is the class of the job i'll launch

```
@Component
public class JobThread implements Runnable {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private Job job;

    public JobParameters jobParameters;

    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(JobThread.class);

    public synchronized void runBatch() {

        jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("LaunchTime", System.currentTimeMillis())
                .addString("TenantID", BatchController.getCurrentTenant().get()).toJobParameters();

        try {
            JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
            log.info("Job's Status:::" + jobExecution.getStatus());
        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException
                | JobParametersInvalidException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.runBatch();

    }

}
```

> the controller which will invoke the job

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("tenant/batch")
public class BatchController {

    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Autowired
    private JobThread jobThread;

    private static ThreadLocal<String> currentTenant;

    @PostMapping("/schedule")
    public void setBatch(@RequestBody BatchBean cron) {

        currentTenant = new ThreadLocal<String>() {
            @Override
            protected String initialValue() {
                new TenantContext();
                return TenantContext.getCurrentTenant();
            }
        };

        //cron = "*/10 * * * * *";


        taskScheduler.schedule(taskExecutor.createThread(jobThread), new CronTrigger(cron.getCron()));

    }
```

I hope that i have been clear enough
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code is flawed and dangerous. you are keeping state in singletons and overwrite that state never do that. Don't recreate your `ThreadLocal` and don't recreate your `JobParamaters`. Only the last one will remain. So it is dangerous. Also you should be programming to interfaces not concrete implementations. Creating a thread for the runnable isn't necessary as your `JobThread` is already `Runnable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your code it isn't thread-safe and thus potentially dangerous. Also your `ThreadLocal` isn't going to work as the job will execute in a different thread, and it won't have access to the `ThreadLocal`.

1. Don't recreate your `ThreadLocal` in your controller. Define it once and leave it like that.
2. Your `JobThread` is a singleton which keeps state (the parameters) so only the last one will remain.
3. Program to interfaces `TaskScheduler` instead of concrete implementatations
4. Don't create a thread as your `JobThread` is `Runnable` already.
5. Instead of your `JobThread` to be a singleton, construct a new one as needed and pass in the required parameters.

Your `JobThread` should look something like this.

```
public class JobThread implements Runnable {

    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(JobThread.class);
    private final JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    private final Job job;
    private final String tenant;

    public JobThread(JobLauncher launcher, Job job, String tenant) {
      this.jobLauncher=launcher;
      this.job=job;
      this.tenant=tenant;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                          .addLong("LaunchTime", System.currentTimeMillis())
                          .addString("TenantID", tenant);

        try {
            JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
            log.info("Job's Status:::" + jobExecution.getStatus());
        } catch (JobExecutionException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your controller inject the needed `JobLauncer` and `Job`. When needed construct a new `JobThread` and pass in the needed information.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("tenant/batch")
public class BatchController {

    @Autowired
    private TaskScheduler taskScheduler;
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private Job job;

    @PostMapping("/schedule")
    public void setBatch(@RequestBody BatchBean cron) {

        //cron = "*/10 * * * * *";
        String tenant = TenantContext.getCurrentTenant();
        JobThread task = new JobThread(this.jobLauncher, this.job, tenant);        
        taskScheduler.schedule(task, new CronTrigger(cron.getCron()));
    }
```

On a final note, the precision of `System.currentTimeMillis` might differ on your OS/System/Architecture. See the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) of said method.

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer and for your notes